# how to access same semphore using sem_open for different user

Tags: semaphore

I have created global semaphore using sem_open() with root user:

sem_t* sem = sem_open("ghMutex", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);

so when I do: ls -al /dev/shm/

-rw-r--r--  1 root root   32 Jan 23 00:23 sem.ghMutex

Now I have a different user in Linux (say User1), which again call the same function sem_open to create semaphore:

sem_t* sem = sem_open("ghMutex", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);

In the last function call, I am getting error EACCES (permission denied), as the semaphore by this name is already created with root user.

My questions:

1) how can I create the semaphore with same name for different user??

2) What is the best practice to have name convention for semaphore in sem_open() so that it can be accessed by multiple users??

Answer (score 0):

You are setting readonly permissions for the other user.

`0644` means:

- 6 (read and write) for the owner
- 4 (readonly) for other group users
- 4 (readonly) for anyone else

According to the man pages:

> Both read and write permission should be granted to each class of user that will access the semaphore.